# Simple form Create nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I have a Households model that has Many visits as nested attributes. I am adding a visit to an existing Household

Using Simple Form I have:

```
= simple_form_for @household,  validate: true, html: { :class => 'form-inline' } do |f|

 . . .
```

Then for the visits I have:

```
= simple_fields_for :visits do |v|

. . .
```

My Controller for the update is:

```
def update
  if household.save
    @household = household
    @household.visits.build
    redirect_to households_path, notice: 'Household was successfully updated.'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

This will update the Household but it does not create a visit, I noticed in the log that  is doing a   save visit

I had this same procedure working with cocoon using:

```
= link_to_add_association( 'New Visit', f, :visits , class: 'btn btn-success btn-large', :render_options => {wrapper: 'bootstrap' },:force_non_association_create => true)
```

I noticed that with Cocoon it was doing create visit instead of save visit

How do I Create a visit?

Comment: could you please try to change your `simple_fields_for` call to `f.simple_fields_for :visits`?

Comment: Tried it and it display multiple visits - One for each visit and it does an update visit  - I wonder if it needs a Visit.new somewhere